# Can I use an EF Database three ways?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a MVC web application that I've done code first to build my database.

I also need to have a console app manage data based on timeframes so, it will also need to access this database which I understand I can use as a Database First model.

However, I also need to build another website as a management dashboard, which I understand will also work as Database First.

Can I do this without having EF in one of the two circumstances nuke the database if I need to make a change to the model?

Comment: you could have your data context is a separate class library that all three projects use (if you wanted to use EF from all)

Comment: Are you asking about using different EF work flows or preventing your database from getting overwritten on model changes? If it is the latter, you can use code first migrations.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: no.  You cannot implement both code-first and data-first EF on the same dataset without encountering a bona fide logistical nightmare.

Converting from one to the other is not *quite* as difficult as you might think, however, if your application is not overly complex.  Based on the tables you've already created, data-first EF should produce objects that are reasonably compatible with your existing code.

Your next steps should look like this:

1. Pick one approach for EF
2. If necessary, convert existing projects to that paradigm
3. Move EF code into a shared class library (as suggested by snow)
4. Implement new projects using that class library to ensure consistency and reduce redundancy

Comment: Thanks, after learning more about this I was able to get a better working implementation using #3